# How to skip the dialog of printing in windows system and print page directly?

Tags: apache-flex, printing

When i use flexprintjob in Flex,it always popup a printing dialog which is printing driver.How can i skip this dialog and print directly?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible with any web tech.
please refer the [FlexPrintJob](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=printing_3.html). **The FlexPrintJob class causes the operating system to display a Print dialog box. You cannot print without some user action.** which is given as a note.